# Change <td> color on condition

Tags: php, html, css

Hi i have this PHP which take sql query divide it into two columns and print table. Now i need to change color of TD where value > 0. I've add color change by class. It's working but not correct. It change color of whole string but not TD cell.

```
$stmt=ociparse($olink, $sql);
if (!$stmt) {
    $e = oci_error($olink); 
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
}
$r =ociexecute($stmt,OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
if (!$r) {
    $e = oci_error($stmt);  // For oci_execute errors pass the statement handle
    print htmlentities($e['message']);
    print "\n<pre>\n";
    print htmlentities($e['sqltext']);
    printf("\n%".($e['offset']+1)."s", "^");
    print  "\n</pre>\n";
}
$ncols = oci_num_fields($stmt);
$cur_dt = 1;
echo "<TABLE border=\"1\" width=\"100%\" align='center' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'  class=\"sortable\">";
/* echo "\n<tr>"; */
for ($i = 1; $i <= $ncols; $i++) {
echo "<th bgcolor=\"#2B75C1\" class=\"header\">".oci_field_name($stmt, $i)."</th>";
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= $ncols; $i++) {
echo "<th bgcolor=\"#2B75C1\" class=\"header\">".oci_field_name($stmt, $i)."</th>";
}
$str=1;
while (oci_fetch($stmt)) {
if ($str % 2 == 1)
{
    echo "\n";
echo "<tr";
$hrr="";
echo ">";
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= $ncols; $i++) {
echo "<td";
echo $hrr;
if (oci_result($stmt, 2) >= $cur_dt)  {$hrr= " class=\"hour\"";echo $hrr;}
echo ">";
echo oci_result($stmt, $i);
}
echo "</td>";
if ($str % 2 == 0) {echo "</tr> \n";}
$str++;
}
echo "</TABLE>";
oci_close($olink);
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[0 in second column should be blue, but it ged "hour" class and change color](http://i.piccy.info/i9/575f84b45d9e212e131116bfbbb59e2d/1424343095/9041/868927/Region.png)

Comment: can you add the <table> html of your output to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a `class` in your `css` file like `.change{background-color:green}` in your
`<td>`

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $ncols; $i++) {
$hrr ="";
if (oci_result($stmt, 2) >= $cur_dt)  {$hrr = 'class="change"';}
echo "<td ".$hrr.">";
 echo oci_result($stmt, $i);
}
 echo "</td>";
if ($str % 2 == 0) {echo "</tr> \n";}
 $str++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css to style a single cell `style="background-color: #2B75C1;"`

If you want to change the color of the string `style="color: #2B75C1;"`

```
echo '<th style="background-color: #2B75C1;" class=\"header\">'.oci_field_name($stmt, $i).'</th>';
```

Comment: I dont have problems with th. I have problems here `if (oci_result($stmt, 2) >= $cur_dt)  {$hrr= " class=\"hour\"";echo $hrr;}` css change color only for td. Please look at picture that i'va attached

Comment: You dont need to attach the css to the th, you can add it to the whole table, tr, th, td, tbody, thead. You only need to add it to the right element.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
echo "<td";
echo $hrr;
if (oci_result($stmt, 2) >= $cur_dt)  {$hrr= " class=\"hour\"";echo $hrr;}
echo ">";
echo oci_result($stmt, $i);
}
echo "</td>";
```

For

```
echo '<td' . (oci_result($stmt, 2) >= $cur_dt ? ' class="hour"' : '') . '>';
//                              ^ shouldn't be there '$i'?
echo oci_result($stmt, $i);
echo '</td>'; // closing tag for <td> in optional, you can remove that to make your HTML more readable.

// remove $hrr variable, you don't need it.
```

Comment: @dend: what's doing now and what it should do? My code add `class=hour` to `TD`s where value is `>= 1`. I thought it's exactly what you need. See my comment, in the first row of my code, you have there `2`, I think there should be `$i`.

Comment: i tried $i , please look at picture that i've attached. it change color of cell that should not be changed

Comment: @dend: image isn't the best medium to show any progress. HTML code you get from this script will be better. I can't debug image.

Comment: `<tr> <td class="hour"> </td> <td class="hour"> </td> <td class="hour"> </td> <td class="hour"> </td> </tr>` . it should be like `<tr> <td class="hour"> </td> <td class="hour"> </td> <td> </td> <td> </td> </tr>`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to replace the "2" with $i . Replace the following code

```
 if (oci_result($stmt, 2) >= $cur_dt)
```

With  the solution.

Solution  1 :

```
if (oci_result($stmt, $i ) >= $cur_dt)
```

Solution 2 :

```
  if ( (oci_result($stmt, $i ) >= $cur_dt) || oci_result($stmt, $i ) > 0)
```

Comment: it change color of wrong parameter $i not helping, i''ve tried

Comment: @dend, can you add the <table> html of your output to the question?